# NodeJS Hive connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, hive

I have a problem with fetching data from Hive with NodeJS. There is an [example for hive module](https://github.com/forward/node-hive/blob/master/examples/test.js) in NodeJS. Here is the code what I'm running (with real ip adress :) ):

```
hive = require('node-hive').for({server:"server.ip.address", timeout:10000});

console.log("before fetch..");

hive.fetch("select * from table", function(err, data) {
  console.log("select * from table");
  data.each(function(record) {
    console.log(record);
  });
});
```

but it doesn't work. In log I got just *before fetch..* so `hive.fetch()` function don't perform.

Does anybody knows what's missing here? I've tried with Hive Query Editor same query and it's work fine.

Comment: I think the node-hive project might be abandoned. No commits for 5 years!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670740/error-in-connecting-node-js-application-to-hive/39529926#39529926 , hope it will help