# Run multiple queries in hive using Node-JS

Tags: node.js, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I am using NodeJS for submitting hive queries.Here is code [Error in connecting node.js application to hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670740/error-in-connecting-node-js-application-to-hive/39529926#39529926), we connecting hive using JDBC with min pool size 10, as in node js async multiple request fire at same time, and hive schedule job FIFO, so when first job done second need to wait, that waiting time increase for concurrent request, so it give me error 502,Code reusing same connection for second time query.

I am using Hadoop (2.7.0) and hive (1.2.1).
So below is my questions

1. Is that issue because Hive job scheduler ( FIFO )
2. Hive not support concurrent query
3. Node js async request creating issues

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: @cricket_007 , edited question with detail